# How to find memory leaks with Clang

Tags: c, memory-leaks, clang, clang-static-analyzer, memory-leak-detector

I have installed Clang in my machine (ubuntu) in order to find memory leaks in my C code. I wrote a sample code in order to check the working of it which is as follows:

```
/* File: hello.c for leak detection */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void *x;

int main() {
  x = malloc(2);
  x = 0; // Memory leak
  return 0;
}
```

I found some options in internet to compile like

```
$ scan-build clang --analyze hello.c
```

and

```
$ scan-build clang -fsanitize=address hello.c
```

But none of them are showing any signs of memory leak.

> scan-build: Using '/usr/bin/clang' for static analysis
>  scan-build:
>   Removing directory '/tmp/scan-build-2015-07-02-122717-16928-1' because
>   it contains no reports.
>  scan-build: No bugs found.

Can anyone kindly tell how to correctly use Clang for Memory leak detection.

Comment: Use [valgrind](http://valgrind.org) when testing your program. Such bugs are impossible to find statically in the general case (but some tools might find some bugs heuristically or conservatively). And `-fsanitize=address`  adds *runtime checks* so you need to run the program.

Comment: did you try `$ scan-build clang -fsanitize=address -g hello.c`?

Comment: $ scan-build clang -fsanitize=address -g hello.c  yes i tried

Comment: Look at the generated code to verify that the compiler didn't optimise away the body of `main`.

Answer (score 4):

Interestingly, the clang static analyzer finds the memory leak if you declare `void *x` inside `main`:

```
int main() {
  void *x = malloc(2);
  x = 0; // Memory leak
  return 0;
}
```

Analyzing this code by running:

```
scan-build clang -g hello.c
```

gives a warning like:

```
hello.c:9:3: warning: Potential leak of memory pointed to by 'x'
  return 0;
  ^~~~~~~~
```

Comment: also, if you use use clang++ and say `x = nullptr` instead of 'x = 0`, even with the global variable, it detects it.